# MacBook Pro stuck at startup with error code "-3001D"

Tags: mac, startup

I have a newer MacBook Pro, but it’s stuck on the startup screen saying:

```
support.Apple.com/Mac/startup

-3001D
```

I haven’t been able to find the relevant article it references and it’s stuck.  I can’t do anything.   I’ve tried shutting down and restarting shut thrice; nothing works. See below for the image when booting

[image]

Comment: Which *specific* MacBook Pro?  “Newer” is subjective.  Did this happen suddenly or were you attempting to do something with the boot drive?  Try booting from Recovery (`Cmd-R`)